# Azure CSP Integration with Indirect Provider using client and secret

Tags: microsoft-partnercenter-java, content-security-policy

We would like to integration Azure CSP Indirect Provider into our portal using client and secret and get the list of customers using REST api.

I need an help here how to achive this feature to get implemented.

Thanks